# Elastic Search synonyms - Delete Action

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, synonym

Are synonyms in Elastic Search (version 6.2.3) stored in the items when these are created/updated or are synonyms applied in every search query to the index?

We need to remove the synonyms of an index with 6 million items and I cannot see in the documentation if removing these synonyms from the index will be enough

`DELETE /api/as/v1/engines/{ENGINE_NAME}/synonyms/{SYNONYM_SET_ID}`

Or it is needed to reindex all the items afterwards, in which case it might be better to delete the current index and create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **If synonyms are applied during inserting the document**

   - Deletion of current synonyms, won't change anything in the existing data of an index, existing data should be searchable by synonyms.
2. **If synonyms are applied during query time**

   - In this case, removing the synonyms will stop searching the document using synonym.

Now the question is whether you are using index-time-analysis or query-time-analysis. You can check in your mappings. E.g

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", // <======== For index time analysis
        "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer" //<====== For Query time analysis  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if the synonym filter is used in the analyzer property is indexed in each item and otherwise if the synonym is used in the search_analyzer is executed in search time, right?

Comment: Correct. Please accept the answer if your query is resolved